# Rspec run all tests even iif i specify specific path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I encountred an issue with Rspec, i don't know why, but event if i specify a test file path in rspec command, it runs all my tests.

rspec spec/path/to/test_spec.rb:28

// it run all files as if it ignore my parameter

Can someone tell me what i'm doing wrong ? Thanks.

My rails_helper.rb:

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require 'spec_helper'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'shoulda/matchers'
require 'webmock/rspec'
require 'sidekiq/testing'
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.pattern = "spec/**/*_spec.rb, spec/**/*.feature" unless ENV['UNIT'] == 'true'
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!

  config.before(:each) do | example |
    stub_request(:post, "https://api.mixpanel.com/track").to_return(:status => 200, :body => "", :headers => {})

    @tracker = instance_double(Mixpanel::Tracker)
    people = instance_double(Mixpanel::People)

    allow(people).to receive(:set)
    allow(@tracker).to receive(:track)
    allow(@tracker).to receive(:people).and_return(people)
    allow_any_instance_of(ApplicationController).to receive(:tracker).and_return(@tracker)
    # Clears out the jobs for tests using the fake testing
    Sidekiq::Worker.clear_all

    if example.metadata[:sidekiq] == :fake
      Sidekiq::Testing.fake!
    elsif example.metadata[:sidekiq] == :inline
      Sidekiq::Testing.inline!
    elsif example.metadata[:type] == :feature
      Sidekiq::Testing.inline!
    else
      Sidekiq::Testing.fake!
    end
  end
end
WebMock.disable_net_connect!(allow_localhost: true)
```

Comment: What does rspec say before it starts the tests? it should say `Run options: ...`

Comment: it says nothing, it just starts tests. I removed the line  "config.pattern = "spec/**/*_spec.rb, spec/**/*.feature" unless ENV['UNIT'] == 'true'" and i fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

So i removed `config.pattern = "spec/**/*_spec.rb, spec/**/*.feature" unless ENV['UNIT'] == 'true'`
 and it works as expected.